# For loop checking if values are equal

Tags: r, loops

I need to create a `for` loop in R to check if weight values for a specific customer ID are equal.

For example:

```
Cust#   Weight
1111    100
1111    100
1111    100
1112    50
1112    75
1112    65
1113    80
1113    80
1113    80
```

In this example, I would want to return the records for 1111 and 1113 because the weights stay the same across the records for that customer.  I would not want the records for 1112 because the weight fluctuates across the three records.

I know this shouldn't be too hard, but I have virtually zero experience with for loops.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you could give some sort of coding start, it would be helpful.

Comment: Also, please provide the desired output as there is confusion as to what it should be.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please edit your question to include the desired output, Also, do you really want a for loop if there are better ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibility with base R:

```
df1[df1$Cust %in% df1$Cust[duplicated(df1)],]
#  Cust Weight
#1 1111    100
#2 1111    100
#3 1111    100
#7 1113     80
#8 1113     80
#9 1113     80
```

The complementary part of the data.frame can be obtained by adding a negation `!` operator:

```
df1[!df1$Cust %in% df1$Cust[duplicated(df1)],]
#  Cust Weight
#4 1112     50
#5 1112     75
#6 1112     65
```

---

A more general version which yields the same result in this example could be

```
var.rows <- aggregate(Weight ~ Cust, df1, var)
df1[df1$Cust %in% var.rows$Cust[!var.rows$Weight],]
```

**data used in this example:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Cust = c(1111L, 1111L, 1111L, 1112L, 1112L, 1112L, 
                1113L, 1113L, 1113L), Weight = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 75L, 
                65L, 80L, 80L, 80L)), .Names = c("Cust", "Weight"), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(Weight)==1) .SD , Cust]
#   Cust Weight
#1: 1111    100
#2: 1111    100
#3: 1111    100
#4: 1113     80
#5: 1113     80
#6: 1113     80
```

Or an option using `base R`

```
i1 <- rowSums(table(df1)!=0)==1
subset(df1, Cust %in%  names(i1)[i1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(cust = rep(1111:1113, each=3),
                 weight = c(rep(1000, 3), 50, 75, 65, rep(80,3)))

df[, count := .N, keyby = .(cust, weight)][count==1, .(cust, weight)]
```

**edit:** and a `dplyr` one:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(cust) %>% filter(n_distinct(weight)==1) %>% distinct(cust, weight)
```

Comment: or `df[, count := .N, keyby = .(cust, weight)][count==1, -c("count"), with=FALSE]`

Comment: One of us seems to have misunderstood the desired output of the OP. Our outputs are complementary... I tried to read the question again and I maintain the impression that the OP wants to remove the non-duplicate entries, but I might be wrong of course.

Comment: Or just `df[, if(uniqueN(weight) == 1L) .SD, by = cust]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes thanks. UniqueN is new-ish, I believe

Comment: @RHertel yes OP is unclear -- first question so will cut him/her some slack

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate to get the count of unique weights for each customer, and use that to find the entries:

```
a <- aggregate(Weight ~ Cust, data=x, FUN=function(y) length(unique(y)))
a$Cust[a$Weight==1]
## [1] "1111" "1113"
```